# make mirroring displays the default in gnome

Tags: gnome-shell, external-monitor

I use gnome with multiple displays.
I use these in a mirroring setup.
However, whenever my external display reconnects (whether by plugging in or by powering on the display), it seems to forget that i preferred for it to mirror.

Is there any way i can set this as the default somehow?

Comment: You may want to review the `monitors.xml` file found in `~/.config`. This file is managed through the Gnome Control Center. I've run into similar situations when using multiple displays, and I noticed that the `monitors.xml` file can get rather messy. You may even want to rename that file (e.g., `orig_monitors.xml`) and have Gnome Control Center recreate it. In my case, the "clean" `monitors.xml` file resolved my display configuration issues.

Comment: @richbl it doesn't seem like i have such a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an external display connect, we need to trigger a shell script
We can do this by using [**udev**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)

First, if you don't have **udev** on your Ubuntu

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt install udev
```

**Monitor (output) UDEV events with udevadm**

This step will be most important for each user. Run `udevadm monitor --environment --udev`. Then connect your HDMI cable.

**udev rule**

Based on the output from the above command, the user created this udev rule at `/etc/udev/rules.d/95-monitor-hotplug.rules`.

```
KERNEL=="card0", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/YOUR_USER_NAME_GOES_HERE/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/hotplug_monitor.sh"
```

Where `YOUR_USER_NAME_GOES_HERE` is your username.

You may want to adjust the `xrandr` options to suit your needs.

First run `xrandr` to detect your current screens:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900       60.0*+   40.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
HDMI3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1680x945       60.0
   [...]
```

To Set the displays so that the external monitor will mirror the current display:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI3 --same-as LVDS1
```

Check your screen display names (LVDS1 etc..).

xrandr script to put at `/usr/local/bin/hotplug_monitor.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/YOUR_USER_NAME_GOES_HERE/.Xauthority

function connect(){
  xrandr --output HDMI3 --same-as LVDS1  
}

function disconnect(){
  xrandr --output HDMI3 --off
}

xrandr | grep "HDMI3 connected" &> /dev/null && connect || disconnect
```

Comment: actually, this seems to do part of the job: it works when you plug out and in, but not when you turn the display off and on.

Comment: @KiaraGrouwstra , well in your question you wrote about screen reconnects which mean plug in plug out behavior  , not on the screen turn off/turn on , you may add it to your question ..

Comment: okay, I've specified the reconnection triggers in the question now