# How can I change the default layout for my displays?

Tags: external-monitor

I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I must re-arrange the screen layout whenever I connect a new external monitor.

Is it possible to have a "default" layout where any ***new*** screen I connect to will use my layout instead?

Ps. This is not reproducible when connecting to a screen I have previously connected to and already set up. It's only new screens.
<sub>*I move a lot around the office, connecting to different screens, which is very common for me.*</sub>

Comment: No, this is not possible. In Xorg, something could be set up with devilspie.

Comment: @vanadium That is dissapointing

Comment: Perhaps a combination of [make mirroring displays the default in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427414/make-mirroring-displays-the-default-in-gnome) and [How to change display's position from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625761/how-to-change-displays-position-from-command-line) could work?